# How to connect to a DB using only Web.config

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, connection-string

**Background:**

I'm setting up a database driven web application in Visual Studio 2012 using MS SQL server 2012 (Dreamspark FTW) or at least I'm trying to.

The DB has been set up and registered using aspnet_config.exe. I have a valid connectionString that I got by connecting to the DB via the server explorer. 
My research tells me that each application I develop should have its own DB and connection string (yes I understand this is not chiseled in stone). If each application I build points to a different DB, there shouldn't need to be a specific connection string in machine.config, am I right? However, I can't get membership to work unless the full connection string is stored in machine.config.

The following attempts have all failed

- Blank connection string in machine.config, complete connection string in web.config

  - both with the same name
  - each with a different name
- No connection string in machine.config, complete connection string in web.config
- Commenting out all references to the machine.config connection string.

I've noticed that under the **system.web -> membership -> providers** tag is an add element with the name AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and a connectionStringName property that points to a specific connection string name. If that specifically named connection string is not found in machine.config, the service won't work. I have tried removing these property but that caused errors too.

**Questions:**

How can I get my application to use the connection string stored in my web.config file?
How also, can I remove all connection strings from machine.config? (if necessary/possible)

Thanks in advance for your insights

Comment: Just a thought, make sure the Web.config is included in the Visual Studio project. You shouldn't need to remove the machine.config ones, but you can use a <clear /> within your Web.config to override them (will need to research this if you're not familiar). Have you configured your membership in Web.config to use SqlProvider?

Comment: I used the web administration tool to set all my providers to aspnetsqlprovider. It didn't make any obvious changes to web or machine.config when I did so.

Comment: What you're attempting to do seems way too overly complicated.  All that needs to be done is to create a new website and then leverage the GUI Toolbox for db connections and the other components to your web app.  The info gets automatically written to the web.config file at the root of the given web site/project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this in your Web.config? This adds the SQL Membership Provider as the default provider. If your membership entry is referencing a specific defaultProvider, that could be your problem too.

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add applicationName="myapp" 
             connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
             name="SqlMembershipProvider" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="60" 
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: It turned out several things were wrong with my installation. After much re-installing, I ran into the same problem and adding the providers as you suggest did the trick.